# Magento Duplicate Product without Custom Options

Tags: magento, duplicates, product

I´m using the following Code to duplicate Products "on the fly", the most of them are Simple Products with Custom options.

Is it possible to duplicate them without Custom Options?

I want to Display them right after i duplicated them - but without custom Options.

Some Ideas?

```
    $clone=$product->duplicate();
    $clone->setSku($clonedSku);
    $clone->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE);   
    $clone->setStatus(1); // AKTIV=1
    $clone->setVisibility(4);
    $clone->setTaxClassId(2);
    $clone->setCategoryIds("93");
    $cloneID=$clone->getId();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to duplicate a product without the custom options (without overriding the product model), but you can duplicate the product and remove the custom options after that.

```
$clone = $product->duplicate();
//all your additional code here
//then delete the options
$options = $clone->getOptionInstance()->getProductOptionCollection($clone);//get all the options
foreach ($options as $option){//loop through the options
    $option->delete();//delete each option
}
```